# Decoding multiple JSON responses using PHP

Tags: php, json, api

I am not able to decode this JSON response into PHP using **json_decode**, your help is appreciated:

JSON response from API

```
{
      "fixtures": [
        {
          "id": 59757,
          "home_team_id": 24,
          "away_team_id": 18,
          "home_score_penalties": 0,
          "away_score_penalties": 0,
              "formation": {
               "home": null,
               "away": null
              },
          "date_time_tba": false,
          "spectators": null,
          "round_id": 4839
        }
      ]
    }
```

PHP:

```
$url = "https://api....";
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents($url), true);
echo $data['fixtures'][0]['home_team_id'];
echo $data['formation'][0]['home'];
```

I get no result!

thank you.

Comment: Your question is incomplete. What do you mean by `multiple`? Where is the actual code? What do you mean by _I failed to decode..._?

Comment: I'v edited my question, please review, thx.

Comment: If you run `echo '<pre>'; print_r($data); echo '</pre>';` you can see the structure of the array. You can access the first ID like this: `echo $data['fixtures'][0]['id'];`. You can use a loop to show the values, but as I said, your question is not very clear.

Comment: I am able to see the whole structure and the values of the arrays using print_r($data), but I need to display specific objects like home_team_id and round_id separately.

Comment: I think the question is better now :/

Comment: have you tried this; `echo $data['fixtures']['home_team_id'];`?

Comment: Does no result mean a blank screen? Please, check [How do I get PHP Errors to display?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display). That `$data['formation'][0]['home'];` should be showing an error. It should be `echo $data['fixtures'][0]['formation']['home'];`

Comment: yes, still blank screen with 'echo $data['fixtures'][0]['formation']['home'];' and "error_log" file has old php records!

Comment: @atoms yes, still blank!

Comment: what was the result of `var_dump($data);`?

Comment: I do not see how this JSON is valid, for starters `"round_id": 4839,` can't end with a comma.

Comment: @atoms `array(1) { ["data"]=> array(0) { } }`

Comment: @Nordenheim yes I corrected it, thx!

Comment: @Basheer listen to Nordenheim! Also check the json is being downloaded by doing `var_dump(file_get_contents($url));`

Comment: @atoms I got `string(11) "{"data":[]}"`

Comment: it doesnt look like you're recieveing the expected JSON. Can you try the URL to confirm the response, and that its valid

Comment: @atoms now I got data `{"data":[{"id":629345,"ht_score":"0-0","ft_score":"2-0",...` but still blank in PHP!

Comment: ok so could you post back the reulst of `var_dump(json_decode(file_get_contents($url)));`

Comment: the problem is your JSON is probably not valid. Can you please use the validator? If `var_dump` returns `null`, your JSON is 100% invalid.

Comment: was assuming he'd read that and would give it a go...  Seemed strange var_dump on file_get_contents was blank though?

Comment: @atoms I got full page of data!

Comment: well done! Will put an answer to cover Nordenheim's comments and your issue with file get contents

Comment: Coming in right now I have no idea why this question has a -4. But I'm turning that into a -3 because as it stands this is a fantastic question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First check that you are recieving output from `var_dump(file_get_contents($url))`.

Then verify that the string returned is valid JSON. Explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38688624/decoding-multiple-json-responses-using-php#38689000) by Nordenheim

Once you can confirm its valid, inspect the JSON decoded data to see how to access the correct value.

`var_dump(json_decode(file_get_contents($url)));`

so the following should be what your looking for;

`$data = json_decode(file_get_contents($url));
 echo $data['data'][0]['id'];`;

Comment: Now data is valid using JSONLint validator, I still get empty page with echo $data['fixtures']['home_team_id'];

Comment: Can you paste contents of last var_dump into your question?

Comment: here are first 3 lines from browser: `{"data":[{"id":629345,"ht_score":"0-0","ft_score":"2-0","et_score":null,"home_team_id":1266,"away_team_id":1275,"home_score":2,"away_score":0,"home_score_penalties":0,"away_score_penalties":0,"formation":{"home":null,"away":null},"date_time_tba":0,"spectators":null,"starting_date":"2016-07-31","starting_time":"13:30:00","status":"FT","minute":90,"extra_minute":0,"competition_id":114,"venue_id":null,"season_id":511,"round_id":7292,"stage_id":873,"aggregate":null,"placeholder":false},`

Comment: using `$data = json_decode(file_get_contents($url));
echo $data['data'][0]['id'];` I got this error: PHP Fatal error:  Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in /home/...

Comment: try to cast the output to an array instead of an object; `$data = json_decode(file_get_contents($url), true); echo $data['data'][0]['id'];`

Answer (score 3):

There are miriads of JSON validators out there. Use any of them before you use `json_decode`.

```
{
    "fixtures": [{
        "id": 59757,
        "home_team_id": 24,
        "away_team_id": 18,
        "home_score_penalties": 0,
        "away_score_penalties": 0,
        "formation": {
            "home": null,
            "away": null
        },
        "date_time_tba": false,
        "spectators": null,
        "round_id": 4839,
    }]
}
```

Your example is no way valid JSON, as `"round_id": 4839,` can't have a comma in the end. The valid JSON would be:

```
{
    "fixtures": [{
        "id": 59757,
        "home_team_id": 24,
        "away_team_id": 18,
        "home_score_penalties": 0,
        "away_score_penalties": 0,
        "formation": {
            "home": null,
            "away": null
        },
        "date_time_tba": false,
        "spectators": null,
        "round_id": 4839
    }]
}
```

Now this JSON returns an array after it's decoded:

```
$json = '{"fixtures": [{"id": 59757,"home_team_id": 24,"away_team_id": 18,"home_score_penalties": 0,"away_score_penalties": 0,"formation": {"home": null,"away": null},"date_time_tba": false,"spectators": null,"round_id": 4839}]}';

var_dump(json_decode($json, true));
```

result:

```
array(1) {
  ["fixtures"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    array(9) {
      ["id"]=>
      int(59757)
      ["home_team_id"]=>
      int(24)
      ["away_team_id"]=>
      int(18)
      ["home_score_penalties"]=>
      int(0)
      ["away_score_penalties"]=>
      int(0)
      ["formation"]=>
      array(2) {
        ["home"]=>
        NULL
        ["away"]=>
        NULL
      }
      ["date_time_tba"]=>
      bool(false)
      ["spectators"]=>
      NULL
      ["round_id"]=>
      int(4839)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Per http://devdocs.io/php/function.file-get-contents replace `true` arg with `FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH` when calling `file_get_contents` in PHP > 5.